# Relative file path in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering what the best way to make this file open location generic for multiple users would be, I have tried a few variations but none will work for me.
The other issue is the pickfile line, when I select cancel in the fileopen dialogue it works fine but when I actually select a file it fails to run the remaining code.

```
Sub IMPORT_DATA()
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
lr = 4
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
**fDialog.InitialFileName = "c:\"    'Location to start looking for a file using file dialouge**
fDialog.Filters.Clear
fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*" 'Looks for excel files
If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fDialog.SelectedItems(1))
End If
If pickfile = False Then Exit Sub 'exits sub if no file name is selected
    For i = 3 To wb2.Worksheets.Count 'Starts workbook search after rate sheets
    lr = lr + 1 'sets start row as 5
        With wb1.Worksheets("JOB NUMBER").Range("A" & lr)    '<----- Change as required
            .Value = CStr(wb2.Worksheets(i).Name)
            .Offset(, 1).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J61").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 2).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J27").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 4).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J39").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 6).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J50").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 7).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J60").MergeArea.Value
        End With
    Next i
wb2.Close False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`pickfile` was never declared and no value was assigned to it.  You can use [SaveSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement) to save the `InitialFileName` and other user related settings.

Having a separate function choose the filename will simplify your code.

```
Sub IMPORT_DATA()
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4
    Const InitialFileName = "c:\"
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = getFileName(InitialFileName)
    If Len(FileName) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'exits sub if no file name is selected
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    lr = FirstRow

    For i = 3 To wb2.Worksheets.Count 'Starts workbook search after rate sheets
        lr = lr + 1 'sets start row as 5
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JOB NUMBER").Range("A" & lr)    '<----- Change as required
            .Value = CStr(wb2.Worksheets(i).Name)
            .Offset(, 1).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J61").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 2).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J27").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 4).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J39").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 6).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J50").MergeArea.Value
            .Offset(, 7).Value = wb2.Worksheets(i).Range("J60").MergeArea.Value
        End With
    Next i
    wb2.Close False
End Sub

Public Function getFileName(Optional InitialFileName As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the a File"
        .InitialFileName = InitialFileName
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx"
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.csv"
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            getFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: That works perfectly. There is one other thing I am going to ask which might be too much. Is there anyway to pull more info from the opened worksheet (wb2) it would be pulling from cell B15 to B26, but it would need to search merged cell C15 to C26 for "OT". If there is not "OT" then it would go into ".Offset(, 8)", etc.(this bit I think I can figure out, just not sure how to search the cells using VBA in the same FOR statement)

Comment: @declan1983 This should do it: `For n = 0 To 10:  Result = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C15:C26").Offset(0, n * 8), "OT"):   Next` .

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, unfortunately it does not seem to work. It does not appear to have any effect on the sheet at all.
I am working on 
    If InStr(wb2.Worksheets(3).Range("C54"), "Hotel") > 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADMIN").Range("E10").Value = wb2.Worksheets(3).Range("J54").MergeArea.Value
        End If

It is the same principle as the "OT" data, just a different set of cells looking for "Hotel", while it works I am struggling to loop it so that any instances that are found are copied over incrementally to a helper row, I can then populate the sheet using formulas.